# Canon Pixma MX494 driver close enough for MX492?

Tags: 14.04, canon

Is the Canon Pixma MX494 driver okay for the MX492? That's the closest match I found from Canon's UK website. [Link to Linux driver.](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx494.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=Linux%20%2864-bit%29)

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, after it is installed the driver describes itself as for the MX490 series.