# Using IJ Scan Utility in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon, pixma

I wish to install the drivers for my Canon Pixma MX494 so that I can use  IJ Scan Utility. Nevertheless, I don't know if I can scan a document with the said printer in Ubuntu 16.04 without necessarily installing these drivers.

---

Alternatively, I will just like to know how to install  IJ Scan Utility on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Operating System... If it is the case where you're responding to this alternative, then please just "kindly comment" about a link, that is "directing" me there not telling me of duplicates because I already read some stuff that is not helping me.

---

Your help is appreciated.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu we tend to use generic drivers (ie. as in "one for all"). Your printer and scanner likely have the same chipset as similar products from Canon.

When you look at this topic: [Canon Pixma MX494 driver close enough for MX492?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690419/canon-pixma-mx494-driver-close-enough-for-mx492) you will see that the MX492 is an older but similar product as the MX494 and that these have worked at least from Ubuntu 14.04.

Canon supplies a driver for this printer and you can download it from [their website](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx494.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=Linux%20%2864-bit%29). It is a debian Package archive so you can use Ubuntu software center to install it (Ubuntu software center should prompt to open it from the download).